# One timer per table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to tap on table cell and start a timer. Every cell should have its own timer. I have managed to set the timer but not independently, when I set one all cells are set.

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! StaffTableViewCell

    if isRunning == false {



        currentCell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "greendot"))!)


        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in

            counter += 1
            let hourPortion = String(format: "%02d", counter / 3600)
            let minutesPortion = String(format: "%02d", counter / 60)
            let secondsPortion = String(format: "%02d", counter % 60)
            //print("\(hourPortion):\(minutesPortion):\(secondsPortion)")

            timeTotal = "\(hourPortion):\(minutesPortion):\(secondsPortion)"

            currentCell.timerLabel.text = timeTotal


            isRunning = true

        }


    }

    tableView.reloadData()


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    timer.invalidate()
    isRunning = false

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! StaffTableViewCell

    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "reddot")) {
        currentCell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }



    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Just have one timer and each time it fires, update the elapsed time in the cells where there is a "timer running".

Comment: I have tried that Paulw11 but I am a beginner and not doing properly, so I need help with the coding. thanks

Comment: @Paulw11 What method would you use to update the values in the individual cells as the timer runs?

Comment: I am using realm database but this is all the code I have thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

- Create a struct to represent each row containing a start time and whether that row is currently running
- Schedule a repeating timer for 0.5 seconds to account for the jitter in `Timer`
- Each time the timer fires, update the visible rows that have "running" timers

```
import UIKit

struct TimerModel {
    private var startTime: Date?
    private var offset: TimeInterval = 0

    var elapsed : TimeInterval {
        get {
            return self.elapsed(since:Date())
        }
    }

    var isRunning = false {
        didSet {
            if isRunning  {
                self.startTime = Date()
            } else {
                if self.startTime != nil{
                    self.offset = self.elapsed
                    self.startTime = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func elapsed(since: Date) -> TimeInterval {
        var elapsed = offset
        if let startTime = self.startTime {
            elapsed += -startTime.timeIntervalSince(since)
        }
        return elapsed
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var timer: Timer?
    var timersActive = 0

    let formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        return formatter
    }()

    var timers = [TimerModel](repeating:TimerModel(), count:30)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func elapsedTimeSince(_ startTime: Date) -> String {
        let elapsed = -startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow

        return self.formatter.string(from: elapsed) ?? "0:00:00"
    }

    func startTimer() {
        self.timersActive += 1
        guard self.timer == nil else {
            return
        }

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
           if let me = self {
            for indexPath in me.tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [] {
                let timer = me.timers[indexPath.row]
                if timer.isRunning {
                    if let cell = me.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                        cell.textLabel?.text = me.formatter.string(from: timer.elapsed) ?? "0:00:00"
                    }
                }
            }
           }
        })
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        self.timersActive -= 1
        if self.timersActive == 0 {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.timer = nil
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.timers.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let timer = self.timers[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageView?.image = timer.isRunning ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "GreenDot") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "RedDot")
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.formatter.string(from: timer.elapsed) ?? "0:00:00"

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.timers[indexPath.row].isRunning = !self.timers[indexPath.row].isRunning
        self.tableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        if self.timers[indexPath.row].isRunning {
            self.startTimer()
        } else {
            self.stopTimer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, just one more thing I want it to start from where the timer stopped not from zero again. can you help with that please? thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer so that you can start and stop and restart a timer without resetting it.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate that!

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, everything is working fine but one thing I am struggling with is, if I refresh app and start timer it won't start for where it was left and start from zero, I want to keep the value, I tried userdefault in so many ways and nothing worked. can you please give me idea how to save in userdefault value of the timer? thanks

Comment: I wouldn't use UserDefaults. I would use Core Data. It has a bigger learning curve but it is a better way to save data. You should ask another question if you need help

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I used ur code but how to use timer in each cell with a specific starting time and how to pause timer (I want to pause time, not talking about stoping timer)

Comment: To pause you just set `isRunning` to `false`. Set it back to `true` to resume the timer.  You can start from a specific value by setting offset to something other than 0