# Countdown timer in table view cell shows different values after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

The problem is described in title, but to be more specific here is a full picture.

I have a custom table view cell subclass with label inside it displaying the countdown timer. When there a small portion of timers it works fine, but with a lot of data I need to display timers far beyond the visible cells and when I scroll down fast and then scroll up fast, the timer values in cells start to show different values until a certain point in time, after which it shows the right value.

I tried different variants for those reuseable cells, but I can’t spot a problem. Help needed!!!

Here is the code of implementation of logic.

**Custom cell subclass:**

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var timer: Timer?

var deadlineDate: Date? {
    didSet {
        updateTimeLabel()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {

    purchaseCellCardView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    let selectedView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    if timer != nil {
        print("Invalidated!")
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}

func configure(for purchase: Purchase) {
    purchaseSubjectLabel.text = purchase.subject
    startingPriceLabel.text = purchase.NMC
    stageLabel.text = purchase.stage
    fzImageView.image = purchase.fedLaw.contains("44") ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "FZ44") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "FZ223")
    timeLabel.isHidden = purchase.stage == "Работа комиссии"
    warningImageView.image = purchase.warningImage
}

func updateTimeLabel() {
    setTimeLeft()
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
        strongSelf.setTimeLeft()
    }
    RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
}

@objc private func setTimeLeft() {

    let currentDate = getCurrentLocalDate()

    if deadlineDate?.compare(currentDate) == .orderedDescending {

        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: deadlineDate!)

        let dayText = (components.day! == 0 || components.day! < 0) ? "" : String(format: "%i", components.day!)
        let hourText = (components.hour == 0 || components.hour! < 0) ? "" : String(format: "%i", components.hour!)

        switch (dayText, hourText) {
        case ("", ""):
            timeLabel.text = String(format: "%02i", components.minute!) + ":" + String(format: "%02i", components.second!)
        case ("", _):
            timeLabel.text = hourText + " ч."
        default:
            timeLabel.text = dayText + " дн."
        }
    } else {
        stageLabel.text = "Работа комиссии"
        timeLabel.text = ""
        timeLabel.isHidden = true
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

private func getCurrentLocalDate() -> Date {
    var now = Date()
    var nowComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: now)
    nowComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    now = calendar.date(from: nowComponents)!
    return now
}

deinit {
    print("DESTROYED")
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

**The most important part of tableView(_cellForRowAt:)**

```
case .results:
        if filteredArrayOfPurchases.isEmpty {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.nothingFoundCell,
                for: indexPath)

            let label = cell.viewWithTag(110) as! UILabel

            switch segmentedControl.index {
            case 1:
                label.text = "Нет закупок способом\n«Запрос предложений»"
            case 2:
                label.text = "Нет закупок способом\n«Конкурс»"
            case 3:
                label.text = "Нет закупок способом\n«Аукцион»"
            default:
                label.text = "Нет закупок способом\n«Запрос котировок»"
            }
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifiers.purchaseCell,
                for: indexPath) as! PurchaseCell

            cell.containerViewTopConstraint.constant = indexPath.row == 0 ? 8.0 : 4.0
            cell.containerViewBottomConstraint.constant = indexPath.row == filteredArrayOfPurchases.count - 1 ? 8.0 : 4.0

            let purchase = filteredArrayOfPurchases[indexPath.row]

            cell.configure(for: purchase)

            if cell.timer != nil {
                cell.updateTimeLabel()
            } else {
                search.getDeadlineDateAndTimeToApply(purchase.purchaseURL, purchase.fedLaw, purchase.stage, completion: { (date) in
                    cell.deadlineDate = date
                })
            }
            return cell
        }
```

**And the last piece of a puzzle:**

```
func getDeadlineDateAndTimeToApply(_ url: URL?, _ fedLaw: String, _ stage: String, completion: @escaping (Date) -> ()) {

    var deadlineDateAndTimeToApply = Date()

    guard stage != "Работа комиссии" else { return }

    if let url = url {
        dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError?, error.code == -403 {
                // TODO: Add alert here
                return
            }
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let data = data, let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8), let purchasePageBody = try? SwiftSoup.parse(html), let purchaseCard = try? purchasePageBody.select("td").array() else {return}

            let mappedArray = purchaseCard.map(){String(describing: $0)}

            if fedLaw.contains("44") {
                guard let deadlineDateToApplyString = try? purchaseCard[(mappedArray.index(of: "<td class=\"fontBoldTextTd\">Дата и время окончания подачи заявок</td>"))! + 1].text().components(separatedBy: " ") else {return}

                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
                let deadlineDateToApply = deadlineDateToApplyString.first!
                let deadlineTimeToApply = deadlineDateToApplyString[1]

                guard let deadlineDateAndTimeToApplyCandidate = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(deadlineDateToApply) \(deadlineTimeToApply)") else {return}

                deadlineDateAndTimeToApply = deadlineDateAndTimeToApplyCandidate
            } else {
                guard let deadlineDateToApplyString = try? purchaseCard[(mappedArray.index(of: "<td>Дата и время окончания подачи заявок<br> (по местному времени заказчика)</td>"))! + 1].text().components(separatedBy: " ") else {return}

                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
                let deadlineDateToApply = deadlineDateToApplyString.first!
                let deadlineTimeToApply = deadlineDateToApplyString[2]

                guard let deadlineDateAndTimeToApplyCandidate = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(deadlineDateToApply) \(deadlineTimeToApply)") else {return}

                deadlineDateAndTimeToApply = deadlineDateAndTimeToApplyCandidate
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(deadlineDateAndTimeToApply)
            }
        })
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
}
```

A few notes:

1. Tried resetting deadlineDate to nil in prepareForReuse() - doesn’t help;
2. Using SwiftSoup Framework to parse HTML as you can see in the last code example if it matters.

Comment: Don't use a timer in the cell. Use a single timer in your view controller and use that to update your model. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246

Comment: I don’t understand how that is applicable in my situation where I get the deadline date from the web via Async dataTask? I understand the concept, but how to implement it in my situation I have no idea

Comment: You need separation of concerns. Fetching the data from the Internet and putting it into your data model is one thing. Displaying it in a tableview is another. Th either answer has some code that shows how to update times in tableview cells.  It is a simple example, but it isn't too hard to have it use an array of deadlines that you load from somewhere rather than the array of start dates in the example.  You shouldn't initiate asynchronous data transfers in `cellForRowAt`. You should have already fetched the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a lot of code but from what you are describing your issue is in reusing cells.

You would do well to separate the timers out of the cells and put them inside your objects. It is where they belong (or in some manager like view controller). Imagine having something like the following:

```
class MyObject {
    var timeLeft: TimeInterval = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            if timeLeft > 0.0 && timer == nil {
                timer = Timer.scheduled...
            } else if timeLeft <= 0.0, let timer = timer {
                timer.invalidate()
                self.timer = nil
            }
            delegate?.myObject(self, updatedTimeLeft: timeLeft)
        }
    }

    weak var delegate: MyObjectDelegate?
    private var timer: Timer?

}
```

Now all you need is is a cell for row at index path to assign your object: `cell.myObject = myObjects[indexPath.row]`.

And your cell would do something like:

```
var myObject: MyObject? {
    didSet {
        if oldValue.delegate == self {
            oldValue.delegate = nil // detach from previous item
        }
        myObject.delegate = self
        refreshUI()
    }

}

func myObject(_ sender: MyObject, updatedTimeLeft timeLeft: TimeInterval) {
    refreshUI()
}
```

I believe the rest should be pretty much straight forward...

Comment: I will try to use your solution and report asap. Sorry for this large bunch of code, but I wanted to give a whole picture

Comment: Is there anything special I need to implement if I’m getting the deadline date asynchronously from the URLSession dataTask in completion handler?

Comment: @GregoryKovler probably not. I assume in completion handler you call something like `self.myObjects = retrievedObjects` `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
search.getDeadlineDateAndTimeToApply(purchase.purchaseURL,
                                     purchase.fedLaw,
                                     purchase.stage,
                                     completion: { (date) in
                cell.deadlineDate = date
            })
```

`getDeadlineDateAndTimeToApply` runs asynchronously, calculates something, and then updates the `cell.deadlineData` in the main thread (which is fine). But in the meantime, while calculating something, the user might have scrolled up and down, the `cell` might have been reused for another row, and now the update updates the `cell` incorrectly.
What you need to do is: Do not store the `UITableViewCell` directly. Instead, keep track of the `IndexPath` to be updated, and once the caluclation is done, retrieve the the cell that belongs to that `IndexPath` and update this.

Comment: I tried to move the logic to data model class, but it seems asynchronous task execution not allowing me to display timer when the cell loads, only after I reload table view. Dunno what to do with this, but it seems more reliable, as @MaticOblak pointed out.

Comment: And may be will be so kind and show me code example. I’m afraid I don’t understand your advice...are you suggesting to update visible cell only?

Comment: In other words how can I keep track of those rows to be updated when calculations are done in my situation and moving timers directly to model?

Comment: Follow @MaticOblak and remove the timer from the cells. Cells are UI elements, which should almost always be dumb, and never create timers, access web services or databases, just to mention a few. This should be done by the controller: Keep track of the model, set up timers and map them to the `IndexPath`/ row in the model; once the timer has finished, grab the cell by using the IndexPath (if still displayed) and update the values in there.

Comment: Ok thnx i’ll try and report about the outcome