# UITableViewCell contents change when scrolling because running a timer in one of the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an table view with 3 cells. In one of the cell I am trying to display a timer which apparently messes up my cells contents when scrolling.

Here is my code:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! StatsuSessionTableViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // do something
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            // do something
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            _ = Timer.every(1.second) { (timer: Timer) in
                let time = self.date.timeIntervalSince(Date())
                cell.statusTitle.text = "TIME"
                cell.statusDescription.text = time.timerFormat

                if time < 0 {
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
            }
            return cell
        }

        return cell
    }
```

If I remove the timer and just display some text, I don't have any issue. But apparently because cell's are destroyed and recreated this messes up my contents, the timer would also appear at indexpath.row 0 not just indepxath.row 2.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: It's a guess, so I won't write it as an answer (yet!), but I think this is because of cell reuse - the first time, the cell is in row 2 and another time it isn't, but the timer is there from the first time. A quick test to see if this is the case would be to create a new cell every time (in line 2) and see if the problem goes away. If so, I'd then look at setting tag or something and invalidate the timer if the tag is set and it isn't in the right row.

Comment: You mean creating the cell inside if statement for row 2 ? Because I tried that and it does the same thing....

Comment: No I meant line 2 of your code panel. the one that begins `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell...`

Comment: Don't run timers in cells. Cells should be a lightweight display of data from your model. If your model should be updated based on time, then do it in the model or the view controller.  Eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246

Comment: @Paulw11: yes, it kinda makes more sense. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that you are creating the timer in the `cellForRowAt:`. The timer also works for the cell that was created by reusing this cell. So you have to implement this timer logic in the `StatsuSessionTableViewCell`. Also implement `prepareForReuse` method in the cell and invalidate the timer there. This is the safest way that I can suggest.