# How to build a button to control the timer individually and show the countdown in the label?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

I just learned Swift 4 months ago and I'm stuck on a problem but I don't know how to fix it. I watched many tutorials on StackOverflow, Youtube and Medium but I can't find a decent solution.

My project is : In the ViewController, there is a TableView and every tableViewCell has a timerLabel, timerNameLabel, playButton and stopButton. When I click the playButton, the cell's timeLabel will start counting down. When I click stopButton, the timer will stop.

I know how to build a correct timer and a correct tableView:

viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



    var myTimerList = CustomTimerList()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myTimerList.timerList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

TimerTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class TimerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var timer = Timer()

    @IBOutlet weak var timerName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLeftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        timer.invalidate()

    }

    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {



    }

}
```

TimerClass:

```
import Foundation

class TimerClass {


    let timerSecond : Int
    let timerName : String

    init(second:Int, name:String) {


        timerSecond = second
        timerName = name

    }

}
```

TimerList:

```
import Foundation

class CustomTimerList {

    var timerList = [TimerClass]()

    init() {

        let customTimer = TimerClass(second: 100, name: "AAA")
        timerList.append(customTimer)
        timerList.append(TimerClass(second: 200, name: "BBB"))
        timerList.append(TimerClass(second: 400, name: "CCC"))
        timerList.append(TimerClass(second: 150, name: "DDD"))
        timerList.append(TimerClass(second: 800, name: "EEE"))
        timerList.append(TimerClass(second: 1000, name: "FFF"))

    }

}
```

but my problems are :

1.I tried to put runTimer in tableViewCell and I linked my playButton to the tableViewCell.swift as an IBAction. Inside this button, is the runTimer, but how do I get the data from the TimerList and show the countdown in the timerLabel, **because I can't get the indexPath.row.**

2.I tried to put the runTimer in the viewController so runTimer can get the indexPath.row but it has another problem: how do I display the runTimer's outcome on the timerLabel and make it countdown, **because the timerLabel was linked in the tableViewCell instead of the viewController.**

I tried many ways like protocol, but I found I can't handle protocol correctly so I don't know how to modify the code correctly.

here is the original file:https://app.box.com/s/0xviuay00pa2ief8b94ar5oh1002q3tn

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246) - it deals with count up, not count down but that is a simple change

Comment: Furthermore, take a look at CADisplayLink. In my experience, it makes timers animations smoother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell

   let item = CustomTimerList.timerList[indexPath.row]
   cell.timerName.text = item.name
   cell.secondLeftLabel.text = "\(item.second)"

    return cell
}
```

//

```
struct CustomTimerList {

  static var timerList = [
      TimerClass(second: 100, name: "AAA"),
      TimerClass(second: 200, name: "BBB"),
      TimerClass(second: 400, name: "CCC"),
      TimerClass(second: 150, name: "DDD"),
      TimerClass(second: 800, name: "EEE"),
      TimerClass(second: 1000, name: "FFF")]

}
```

//

Instead of worrying about the current content of the count down labels and store the current value , get the current value from it's text and if it's not zero decrease it and set it back , Also take not that you currently don't have a stopping mechanism for the timers if the user scrolls so after this line in `cellForRowAt`

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell
 cell.timer?.invalidate()
```

//

```
class TimerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var timer:Timer?
}
```

Comment: Yes!!!! It works!!!!! Khan you saved my life!!!! but I have a final question, i found that when I scroll the tableview, the timer will stop! and it will start count down when I stop scroll

Comment: I add this : RunLoop.current.add(self.updateTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)  but the xCode said: Cannot invoke 'add' with an argument list of type '(() -> (), forMode: RunLoopMode)'

Comment: Oh I fixec it! Thank you again! I will vote you but the system say I need some time to have the "vote" feature. Thanks!!!

Comment: but I found that when I was scrolling the tableView, the running timer that scrolled out of the screen and I scrolled it back, the running timer will be reset and stop...