# Timer will reset and stop running during scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

[timer.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2AH9.gif)

↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑  I show the problem in this GIF     ↑↑↑↑↑

There is a timer and stratButton in the tableView cell, when I click the Button, the timeLabel will start running.

Now the problem is when I scroll the running timer out of the screen and scroll it back, the timer will reset and stop.

Hope someone can help me! I check many solution but they didn't work for me! I am almost cry.

my cellForRow:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell

    cell.timer?.invalidate()
    let item = myTimerList[indexPath.row]
    cell.timerName.text = item.timerName
    cell.secondLeftLabel.text = "\(item.timerSecond)"      
    return cell

}
```

I created a small project contained my code for you to modify : https://app.box.com/s/axluqkjg0f7zjyigdmx1lau0c9m3ka47

Comment: Don't use a timer per cell. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246 for a better solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to preserve the state of each cell

```
class Service {

   static let shared = Service()

   var myTimerList = [TimerClass]()
}
```

//

here i added another 2 vars , why `timerName` is left despite you have to init them the same because `current` will hold the changing value

```
class TimerClass {

    let timerSecond : Int
    let timerName : String
    var current: Int
    var isPlaying = false

    init(second:Int, name:String) {

        timerSecond = second
        timerName = name
        current = second
     }

}
```

//

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell


    let item = Service.shared.myTimerList[indexPath.row]
    cell.tag = indexPath.row // to access the array inside the cell
    if item.isPlaying {
      cell.play()     // add play method to the cell it has same button play action
    }
    else {
      cell.timer?.invalidate()
    }
    cell.timerName.text = item.timerName
    cell.secondLeftLabel.text = "\(item.current)"      
    return cell

}
```

//

inside the cell when the button is clicked , change isPlaying property to true and to false when stopped like this

```
// here self is the cell itself 

Service.shared.myTimerList[self.tag].isPlaying = true
```

also when the timer ticks change

```
Service.shared.myTimerList[self.tag].current = // value
```

Comment: Hey, Khan! Thank you for your help, I integrate your code into my code, and now the timer won't reset but it will still be stop running if I scroll it out of the screen, I try to change some code to fix it but it doesn't work...I think i might misunderstand some steps you mentioned above...could you help me check where I made mistakes? I updated my code and put in here : https://app.box.com/s/hpu6xidy6c1gtcyp6d9uq6p5xwft6rr2

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing `UITableViewCell`. It means once cell is out of screen, it will be reused for the cell getting into the screen. Whenever it happens, it calls the delegate method - means `cell.timer?.invalidate()` is invoked again and again.

Comment: yes, but when I delete cell.timer?.invalidate() and my timer will be reset and stop if I scroll it out... could you give me some better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `cell.timer?.invalidate()` from `cellForRowAt` method, because every time you scroll the `tableView` this method is called to display new cells. In your case when you have started a timer for a cell and that cell is not in the view, next time you scroll to bring that cell again to the view `cell.timer?.invalidate()` causes it to stop.

Comment: no, I remove it but my timer still reset and stop running...could you show me another way? here is the resource : https://app.box.com/s/axluqkjg0f7zjyigdmx1lau0c9m3ka47