# reload selected collection cell in independent time interval

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to make countdown timer app with collectionView.

Features & Functions:

- Each cell has own label and timer function.
- CountDown timer will run if user touches a cell.
- Time string have to updated as timer run.

I successfully build a timer in each cell but I'm stuck updating timeLabel (reload selected cell).

Please check the codes below and give me some hint.

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


var recipeList: TimeRecipeList
var timer = Timer()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    recipeList = TimeRecipeList()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let width = (view.frame.size.width - 10) / 2
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddItemSegue" {
        if let addItemVC = segue.destination as? AddRecipeViewController {
            addItemVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
extension ListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipeList.item.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RecipeListCell", for: indexPath)
        let item = recipeList.item[indexPath.row]
        configureText(for: cell, with: item)
        return cell
    }

    func configureText(for cell: UICollectionViewCell, with item: TimeRecipe) {
        if let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel {
            label.text = item.name
        }

        if let label = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel {
            let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
            formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
            let timeString = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(item.time))
            label.text = timeString
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RecipeListCell", for: indexPath)
        let item = recipeList.item[indexPath.row]

        let cellTimer = TimerControl()
        cellTimer.second = item.time
        cellTimer.timerRun()

        configureText(for: cell, with: item)

    }


    class TimerControl {

        var timer = Timer()
        var second: Int = 0


        func timerRun() {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(countDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

        @objc func countDown() {
            //let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RecipeListCell", for: indexPath)

                if second <= 1 {
                    timer.invalidate()
                } else {
                    second -= 1
                    //collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

                    //MARK: Reload selected cell
               }
        }

    }


}

extension ListViewController: AddRecipeViewControllerDelegate {
    func addRecipeViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: AddRecipeViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func addRecipeViewControllerDisSave(_ controller: AddRecipeViewController, didFinishAdding item: TimeRecipe) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
        let rowIndex = recipeList.item.count
        recipeList.item.append(item)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: 0)
        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
    }


}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you use a single timer, rather than trying to manage a timer per-cell.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246) for an approach.  That answer counts "up" - To count "down" you need to calculate the end date; e.g. `Date()+15.0` to end 15 seconds from now.

Answer (score -1):

```
@objc func countDown(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if second <= 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
        } else {
            second -= 1
            //MARK: Reload selected cell
            yourarray[indexPath.row] = newvalues
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show me where you are using that function ?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand exactly what you mean. Instead I edit code above. Thank you.