# How to handle timer time and functionality in UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm adding a timer in every cell and every cell has its own time, API send me the expire time to alarm the user i need to play timer on the expire time for every specific cell, i'm facing problem when i scroll the table view and it deque the cell then timer does not work properly, And how i can handle it for those cells which are not present on the screen. suppose my array has 100 items but at the time i can show only 10 item on screen then how i'll check and alarm the user for 20th or 30th cell (item).
And how i check alarm for every single cell. Please explain it.

i've tried with indexPath but its not helpful for me for those cells which are not on screen and making issue on scroll.

Comment: Consideration, rather than having a `Timer` for EACH cell/item.  Have one, which ticks at a small, but regular interval.  Use it to determine which item(s) have timed out and then execute the required functionality

Comment: But how it will work for those cells which are not on screen. or not in Que

Comment: It shouldn't care.  The "central" timer only cares about the whole model, not the UI

Comment: It's very bad practice to run timers in a **view**. Run it in the **model** and use callbacks or protocol / delegate to be able to update the UI dynamically when the cell is on screen.

Comment: Write down Timer() your in model or view model if you are working on MVVM. second update your elapse time when your app will come form background state(if your app doesn't support background modes)

Comment: Here is one approach - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to set timer in Model. if you are work on Model-View-ViewModel...second update your elapse time when your app will come form background state(if your app doesn't support background modes)