# Multiple Timers in Tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am trying to have timer for each row which is added manually when user clicks on add button.

Start time is set to 100units(not important for the question) and it should count down.

When new row is added it will have it's own timer started and display the value on this new row.

I tried to have timer in each cell but this is creating issue when dequeuing, so I created array of timer to hold corresponding timer for each cell. Problem I am facing right now is how to update the cell value every second(timer interval)

[MultipleTimersTableView_Gist](https://gist.github.com/AvinashRamireddy31/96bac4a57e10664bbc439f6470da4a59) is the link for the code I wrote so far. I thought of using delegate to update the cell but not sure with the best approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

[image: Dequeue issue]

Timers should show the time in increasing order because each row is created(along with timer)from top to bottom meaning first will have less time than next. Looks like while dequeueing something messed up.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/AvinashRamireddy31/7a856aaa4ce229e76d6f303a98c6c06d) is the gist I used for above screenshot

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing while dequeuing?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can handle `timers` in each `UITableViewCell`.

**Create a custom `UITableViewCell`**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    //MARK: Internal Properties
    var handler: ((Int)->())?

    //MARK: Private Properties
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var counter = 100 {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.label.text = "\(self.counter)"
                self.handler?(self.counter)
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: Internal Methods
    func configure(with counter: Int) {
        self.counter = counter
        self.setTimer()
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods
    private func setTimer() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {[weak self] (timer) in
            if let counter = self?.counter, counter > 0 {
                self?.counter -= 1
            } else {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In the above code,

1. I've created a `label` that will update the `counter` value in `UI`.
2. `handler` - it will and store the updated `counter` value somewhere (in `ViewController`, explained further) when the `cell` is moved out of the screen
3. `timer` - schedule the `timer` in the `cell` with `timeinterval = 1`
4. `counter` - current `counter` value for each `cell`

**In the `ViewController`,**

```
class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    let numberOfCells = 20
    var timerArr = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.timerArr = [Int](repeating: 100, count: numberOfCells)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.numberOfCells
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.configure(with: self.timerArr[indexPath.row])
        cell.handler = {[weak self] (counter) in
            self?.timerArr[indexPath.row] = counter
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

In the above code,

1. `timerArr` - keeps track of the `counter` value for each `cell` in the `tableView`.
2. In `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, the `counter` for each `cell` is updated using the `handler` we created previously in `CustomCell`.

Comment: I tried to use your code but still there is issue with dequeueing rows. Please check my updated question with attached screenshot of the issue after using ur code mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one timer for all the cells. When creating your object and adding it to the datasource, record the dateAdded = Date(), then when the cells are rebuilt on the timer fire, get the seconds count for each cell from the dateAdded field and update the cell in cellForRowAtIndex.