# Implementing countdown timers in custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

I'm newbie in Xcode and swift and now I'm trying to create iOS app which allow user to create multiple custom `countdown timers`. I'm using `UITableViewController` with `UITableViewCell` and `UIViewController` for adding new `timers`. But I cannot figure out how to implement them working together. And how to implement in custom cell timer settings.

**My UITableViewController cell:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timer", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell
    cell.timerLabel.text = timersNames[indexPath.row]
    let sec = timersSeconds[indexPath.row]
    cell.timerTime.text = formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(sec))
    print(sec)
    return cell
}
```

**My custom cell UITableViewCell with timer functionality:**

```
class TimerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var delegate: TimerCellDelegate?


@IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var timerTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var pauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var resetButton: UIButton!

var seconds = 10
var timer = Timer()
var hasTimerStarted = false
var isResumed = false



func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,
    selector: (#selector(TimerTableViewCell.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

@objc func updateTimer() {
    if seconds < 1 {
        timer.invalidate()
        //Send alert to indicate "time's up!"
    } else {
        seconds -= 1
        timerLabel.text = formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    }
}


func formattedTime(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
    let hours = Int(time) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
}




@IBAction func timerStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapTimerStart(sender.tag)
    if hasTimerStarted == false {
    runTimer()
        self.playButton.isEnabled = false
    }

}

@IBAction func timerPause(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapTimerPause(sender.tag)
    if self.isResumed == false {
        timer.invalidate()
        hasTimerStarted = false
        self.isResumed = true
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Resume",for: .normal)
    } else {
        runTimer()
        self.isResumed = false
        hasTimerStarted = true
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
    }


}

@IBAction func timerReset(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapTimerReset(sender.tag)
    timer.invalidate()
    seconds = 10
    timerLabel.text = formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    hasTimerStarted = false
    isResumed = false
    self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    self.playButton.isEnabled = true
   }
}
```

> How I can put the code from custom cell to UITableViewController cell config and make them work together?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't want a timer in each cell, since the cells are reused. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246

Comment: Thanks. It's good addition, but I want to implement countdown timer.

Comment: The same approach works for a count down timer

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://medium.com/programming-with-swift/create-a-custom-uitableviewcell-with-swift-6d7eb7389f19) tutorial should help you with custom cells in tableViews. Hope it helps!